# warning: assignment to ‘struct node_t *’ from incompatible pointer type ‘node_t *

Tags: c, struct, variable-assignment

I'm working with a linked list and trying to assign information from nodes in a list (node_t) to a separate struct (list_stats_t)

```
struct node
{
    char firstName[50], lastName[50], major[50], classStanding[50];
    bday bd;     // this struct just contains int values of day, month, and year

    struct node* next;
};
typedef struct node node_t;

struct stats
{
 // node pointer pointing at the oldest and youngest person in the list
    struct node_t* oldest;
    struct node_t* youngest;

 // holding the number of birthdays in each month (0 = Jan. & 11 = Dec.)
    int numBD[12];
}; typedef struct stats list_stats_t;
```

```
list_stats_t getListStats(node_t *head)
{
    node_t* temp = head;

 // creates object to be returned and initializes it to the first node in a list
    list_stats_t stat;
    node_t* oldest = temp;
    node_t* youngest = temp;

    while (temp != NULL)  // loops through the list to find the oldest and youngest person
    {
     // if current node isn't the oldest, set the oldest to the next node   
        if (isOlder(oldest) == false)
            { oldest = temp->next; }
        if (isOlder(youngest) == false)
            { youngest = temp->next; }

        temp = temp->next;      // next value
    }

 // compiler warnings
    stat.oldest = oldest;
    stat.youngest = youngest;

    return stat;
}
```

I was expecting the node_t values in struct stats to be assigned to the node_t values within getListStats(). There aren't any compiler errors, just warnings but I prefer to avoid those as well

Comment: Change the line in the declaration of `struct stats` from `struct node_t* oldest;` ==> `node_t* oldest;`. Do the same for `youngest`, too. What you've written is, in effect, `struct struct node* oldest;` and that doesn't make sense...

Comment: you have defined a `struct node` and `node_t` . As far as I can see you have no `struct node_t` defined in your code.

Comment: OT: Function not shown would seem to indicate you may wind up pointing to NULL for either `oldest` or `youngest`... This needs attention.

Comment: @Fe2O3, Re "*What you've written is, in effect, `struct struct node* oldest;` and that doesn't make sense*" No. `struct node_t *` does not mean that and `struct node_t *` does make sense (grammatically). It's not correct because it's a different type than intended, but it does make sense.

Answer (score 3):

You have two names for your node type:

- `struct node`
- `node_t`

`struct node_t` is different than these, and not the type you intended to use.

Answer (score 1):

The source of the compiler message is `node_t` vs `struct node_t` where `node_t` is a `typedef`, not a struct tag.

To explain *why* it would spit out something as strange as "warning: assignment to ‘struct node_t *’ from incompatible pointer type ‘node_t *":

C has the concept of *incomplete type*, meaning it allows you to use placeholders for a type to be declared later. An example of this is `struct node* next;` inside your `struct node { ... };` declaration. The compiler doesn't actually know what a `struct node` is by the time it reaches `struct node* next;` - this is just a placeholder. Once the compiler reaches the final `;` after the struct declaration, then it knows what a `struct node` is from there on.

Incomplete type/forward declaration is useful in various similar situations. Although we cannot declare an object of an incomplete type until the compiler knows the object declaration - we can only declare a pointer to one.

Therefore something like `int main (void) { struct bananas* p; }` is a valid C program, even though there's no such struct declaration present anywhere - `p` is a pointer to an incomplete type. And as such we cannot really use `p` until a complete type has been spotted by the compiler.

So in your case the typo `struct node_t*` created a pointer to an incomplete type, different from `struct node`/`node_t` which at that point is a complete type. They are not compatible types, hence the compiler message. Strictly speaking this made your program invalid C, but the compiler chose to create a non-standard executable anyway. Which it may do as long as it gave the programmer a message about spotted problems. (If you want to prevent that with gcc-like compilers, then compile as `-pedantic-errors`.)